# Calculation Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to add a column in a table to calculate the numner of weeks between two dates which are in two other columns. The columns are:

```
[DateStart] [date] NULL,
[DateEnd] [date] NULLNumOfWeeks,
[NumOfWeeks] [int]
```

If the end date is NULL the calcualtion whould be number of weeks between StartDate and current date.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Comment: The result would be 3, i.e. the number of full weeks. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ADD
[NumOfWeeks] AS DATEDIFF(week, DateStart, COALESCE(DateEnd, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly except where the End Date is NULL. If the End Date is NULL the calcualtion should be the number of weeks between the Start Date and the current date. Cheers.

Comment: I've added that case to my answer.

Comment: Looks like there are two issues in the syntax: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'. and The close bracket on GETDATE() says there Incorrect syntax near ')'. Expecting '(', or select.

Comment: I am using SQL Express 2008 :-)

Comment: Interesting. That code works for me, I just tried it. I'm not sure what limitations there are to using SQL Express 2008 for this stuff. I'll look into it.

On the other hand, why are you using a calculated column? Why not perform the test in your select statement? That seems more robust.

Comment: What query exactly are you running when you get the syntax error? Copy and paste this and see if it still occurs: `CREATE TABLE TestTable ( DateStart DATE, DateEnd DATE, [NumOfWeeks] AS DATEDIFF(week, DateStart, IIF(DateEnd IS NULL, GETDATE(), DateEnd)) )`. That works verbatim on my SQL Server, and the difference in version shouldn't be relevant from what I've seen online.

Comment: Same errors as before. As to why, I am connecting to this table through an excel pivot table and need to bring the number of weeks through. I figured this would be a simple way to do it.

Comment: I have zero experience whatsoever with Excel Pivot tables, excuse my ignorance, but I would have expected them to have some way of specifying a `SELECT` to pull data through. Ah well. If this doesn't work, I doubt that would, anyway. Hmm. Wait, it worked before I added in the IIF, right?

Comment: Yes, the code without the IIF worked when there was both a Start Date and End Date. I just needed the records without the End Date to use the current date for the calculation.

Comment: I found it. Iif wasn't introduced until 2012. Sigh. I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: This is actually a better way of doing it, too. It should have occurred to me earlier. Does that do it?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I was also looking for an answer and come across using CASE instead which works. However for S#its and Giggles I also tried you solution and that also worked. Thanks for your help. I will post my solution below but mark yours as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Case method that also worked...

```
ALTER TABLE Timeslots ADD
[NumOfWeeks] AS DATEDIFF(week, DateStart, CASE when DateEnd IS NULL THEN GETDATE() Else DateEnd END)
```